# Custom column size on bootstrap (without affect responsive design)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create on my page a really tiny left menu with bootstrap like this :

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 leftMenu"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 main"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 rightMenu"></div>
</div>
```

However col-md-1 is too large for my menu. I would like a width equal to 50px;

I don't find a solution to have a menu with a size inferior to the minimal column, without affect the responsive design of my page

Anyone have an answer to my problem ?

Comment: Don't use bootstrap and hand code your site... imo, bootstrap sucks.

Comment: You could use percentage widths instead of col's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep using Bootstrap, you could define new columns widths, *e.g.* 0.5 / 12 and 7.5 / 12:

```
col-md-0-5 | col-md-7-5 | col-md-4
col-sm-0-5 | col-sm-7-5 | col-sm-4
```

If you check the [`bootstrap.css`](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) file, you can define the new `col-md-0-5` and `col-md-7-5` classes as follows:

```
.col-md-0-5, .col-md-7-5 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-0-5, .col-md-7-5 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-md-0-5 {
        width: 4.16666667%;
    }
    .col-md-7-5 {
        width: 62.5%;
    }
}
```

Just follow the same logic to define the new `col-xs-0-5` and `col-xs-7-5` classes.

Answer (score 1):

i have a solution for this and use it for my project you can make a file in sass directory with own name and add to main bootstrap sass file 
first open _bootstrap.scss file and add this to last line

```
 @import "bootstrap/my-responsive";
```

my-responsive is your file name

and put your custom css to that file (_my-responsive.scss) for any customize responsive size bootstrap screen like this 
put your css for col-sm (small screen)

```
@media screen and  (min-width: $screen-sm-min){ your own css }
```

this css just load in sm size with bootstrap standard size

for example

```
@media screen and  (min-width: $screen-sm-min){ .leftMenu {width:20px} }
@media screen and  (min-width: $screen-md-min){ .leftMenu {width:55px} }
```

in this case finaly you have one class with 20px width in sm screen and 55px in md screen so your responsive is ok and has your specific size

Answer (score 1):

**Assign width to the div**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-1 col-sm-1 well leftMenu " style="width:15px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 well main "></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 well rightMenu "></div>
  </div>
```

[Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/dLjf67EHlUqKcZVvTcVj/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.parentdivClass .row .col-md-1.col-sm-1.leftMenu{
/*your style*/
}
```

---

this CSS solve your problem but  the responsiveness of the bootstrap will get affected for sure.